# How to handle async calls with Angular 2?

Tags: angular

When I read Angular 2 docs it says Angular working asynchronously but when I run below code it outputs;

```
action1 completed
All actions completed
```

I think above code working synchronously. How can I call action1 function asynchronously?

```
startPoint(){

    action1();
    console.log("All actions completed");
}



action1(){
   var i;
   var t = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < 99999999; i++){
       t += i;
   }
   console.log("action1 completed");
}
```

**EDIT:** I want to call action1 function with a new Thread. It will call action1 but doesn't wait for action1 to complete and continue with new line.

Expected output:

```
All actions completed
action1 completed
```

Comment: Because that has nothing to do with an asynchronous operation. Also it has nothing to do with angular specifically.

Comment: Keep reading the documentation, specifically the tutorial and you will get to using server side calls which illustrate how async operations work.

Comment: @hellzone where is the async code?

Comment: @Igor Problem is server side I think. I didn't make any call to server side. All operations are on client side. So how can I call action1 function with a different Thread?

Comment: @Ferus7 I edited my question.

Comment: @hellzone no multithreading in javascript, the way to go for concurrent code is async code. I really recommend to you start learning reactive programming in typescript, with **Observables**, is the best async way to go in TypeScript, IMHO

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a customizable asynchronous function. What you can do is use some of the technology like

- `setInterval`
- `setTimeout`